# using $group Aggregation in Jongo

Tags: java, mongodb, jersey, jackson, jongo

I am using Jongo to query my MongoDB with Java. My question is "How can I save a sum into a Class attribute?"

I have a Class OffersByPostalCode

```
public class OffersByPostalCode {

private String _id;
private String offers;

public OffersByPostalCode(String _id, String offers) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.offers = offers;
 //Getters, setters & toString are here 
}
```

SO, I'am trying to query my DB and get Offers group by postalCode Using Jongo, here is the query :

```
list_job = collection.aggregate("{$group:{ _id :'$postalCode',offers:{'$sum':1}}}).as(OffersByPostalCode.class);
```

The problem is that when I get my result from the query I have my postalCode but the offers attribute which is the sum of offers by postalCode is always NULL.
It works fine in MongoDB shell.

Comment: You should remove the simple quotes around $sum

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
`list_job = collection.aggregate("{$group:{ _id :'$postalCode',offers:{$sum:1}}}).as(OffersByPostalCode.class);`
```